# problem in shell script

Tags: bash, unix, shell, awk

I am trying this option

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo $1
awk '{FS="=";print $2}' $1
```

and on the command line

```
test_sh INSTANCE=VIJAY
```

but awk is failing. Is there any problem here?
Basically I need the value `VIJAY` passed on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for `awk`, the second parameter is a name of the file to process.
So you asked it to process the file named `INSTANCE=VIJAY`

Instead, do

```
echo "$1" | awk '{FS="=";print $2}'
```

Just to be clear, what this does is pass the input to be processed to awk via standard input through a pipe from output of `echo`; instead of awk reading it input from a file.

To quote from [Awk manual](http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-awk-manual.html):

> If there are no files named on the command line, gawk reads the standard input.

Comment: put the FS variable in BEGIN block.

Answer (score 3):

ksh (and Bash) can do the splitting for you:

```
#!/bin/ksh
var="${1%=*}"
val="${1#*=}"
echo "Var is $var"
echo "Val is $val"
```

Running it:

```
$ ./scriptname INSTANCE=VIJAY
Var is INSTANCE
Val is VIJAY
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a simpler one is

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $1
echo $1 | cut -d= -f2
```

as `cut` can split on the equal sign as well and then show the second token.  Also note that the passing `$1` to `awk` was not correct as that argument is not a file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you left the pipe (|)

```
echo $1 | awk '{FS="=";print $2}'
```

Alternative

```
echo $1 | cut -d'=' -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo $1 | cut -f2 -d=
```